# What does Invalid token 'void' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration error mean?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace namespaceaaa
{
    class Anjila
    {
        Static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int[,] twobyythree = new int[2,3] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
            Console.WriteLine(twobyythree);
        }
    }
}
```

was expecting output in [2,3] array form.

Comment: All c#'s reserved words are lowercase - `Static` should be `static`.  Fix that and your output would be `System.Int32[,]`

Answer (score 1):

`Static` is not a keyword in C#.  All keywords are lower case.

CHange the line to this and see what happens.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
```